# Android Instance Variables

Tags: java, android, performance

Are instance variables preferred over local variables or vice versa? For instance, with using `SharedPreferences`, should it be declared at the top of the class and then referenced throughout or should it just be declared in each method it is needed?

I am wondering if there would be a large difference in memory usage since the instance variable would last as long as the activity; however, it would be cleaner since I would not need to instantiate it in every method it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **prefer local variables over class-variables** any day.

Having a lot of instance-variables that impact code-execution in different methods leaves you with a lot of state. That makes it very hard to reason about it, for example when you're trying to step through a function in your head in order to find a bug.

I like to take this a step further by making methods that don't manipulate the objects state `static` and passing everything they need as parameters. That way, you can look at this function completely isolated from the class context. **My goal is to end up with [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which are very easy to reason about.**

If it ever becomes necessary to make one of those functions impure, that might indicate poor design decisions!

---

There are however a few things where it makes sense to "cache" them at class level:

- Views from your Layout. `findViewById()` is surprisingly costly, so if you have a view that you need in more then just one method, you should "cache" it. The [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library makes that very easy.
- Database connections or really anything that has significant costs attached to opening/closing it. **But**, don't keep those "laying around" in your Activity. Conceal them in a class and make that class responsible for handling the opened resource.

Generally speaking: class-variables make your class more statefull. This is fine for classes that are statefull by nature (e.g. `Activity` or `Fragment`), but you should try to minimize the amount of state you have to worry about.

Comment: Good to know about the `findViewById()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to come down to a time/space tradeoff, in which case I would say the answer depends. I would normally default to favoring reading the persisted object once, at time of object construction, but especially if there is a significant performance cost when doing so. However, if in memory is at premium and storing the object in question is space cost prohibitive, then I would consider reading it on an as needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the use that you want for that variables. If you want a variable that will be needed in the whole class you will need to declare it on the top of the class but if, on the contrary, the variable that you are going to declare it's just use on a method, you should declare it inside this method.

I can't say to you if it uses more memory or less (are concepts that I really don't know) but I can ensure that your code will be more clear in this way.

I'm not secure about that but I think that each time you declare a variable it consumes a bit of your memory usage, so, in conclusion, it will consume more memory usage if you have a variable in each method instead of in the top of the class. If someone that know this have to correct me, please do it.

I expect it will helps a bit to you!

Comment: Not the declaring of a variable takes up space (declaring = "this will be an int") but the initialization (calling the constructor/assigning a value) costs memory. The only **maginal** problem attached to local variables is which are not primitives is, that they'll have to be garbage collected when there are no more references to it.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Yes, I wanted to made reference to the initialization instead of declaration. Thanks for correct me and thanks for the explanation!